Lightweight-PLA (LW-PLA)
I have been trying to print lightweight PLA for a project. I settled on an RC airplane model found online.
My initial prints were very problematic, so, I looked up other people's printing settings and made adjustments. After 10 or so prints I believe I have mostly configured it but there are still some areas I cannot seem to get to print right. My last adjustment was changing from 260 °C printing temperature and 0.45 mm/s flow rate to 250 ° and 0.5 mm/s respectively. That fixed a weird problem where the internal walls separated from the outer skin of the model.
Now the main problem is some "overhangs" appear to be collapsing.
Material:  I'm using Esun branded material, slicing on Cura and printing on an Ender 3 Pro with a G10 bed, a Sprite Pro extruder, auto bed leveling, an enclosure and Klipper firmware.
I have attached my Cura profile and the G-code it was printed from.
Does anyone know how to tackle that problem?
After some extra troubleshooting, it appears as if part of the model is not being sliced properly (I'm slicing in vase mode). If I slice for a 0.05 mm layer height, the problem appears to get solved. However I still do not know how to get Cura to slice that part properly without selecting an unreasonably small layer height.

0.25 mm layer height

0.05 mm layer height







Vase mode cannot do complex geometries, so better not use it. Try slicing in non-vase mode.

Did you get it right in the end ?
I bought myself a Ender 3 V3 and tried LW-PLA for the first time, it was a mess ...

Like Oscar mentions: Vase mode can only slice models with no internal structure. I am surprised you got a model like in your pictures.
Slice the model with vase mode off and play around with the "print thin walls" setting to see walls that might be less than 0.4mm wide.
